# Unable to parse APL Symbol using ANTLR

Tags: antlr, apl

I am trying to parse APL expressions using ANTLR, It is sort of APL source code parser. It parse normal characters but fails to parse special symbols(like '←')

expression = N←0

**Lexer**

```
/* Lexer Tokens. */

NUMBER:    
 (DIGIT)+ ( '.' (DIGIT)+ )?;

ASSIGN:
    '←'
    ;

DIGIT : 
    [0-9]
    ;
```

Output:

```
[@0,0:1='99',<NUMBER>,1:0]
**[@1,4:6='â??',<'â??'>,2:0**]
[@2,7:6='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:3]
```

Can some one help me to parse special characters from APL language.

I am following below steps.

1. Written Grammar
2. "antlr4.bat" used to generate parser from grammar.
3. "grun.bat" is used to generate token

Comment: You only showed that the arrow is not properly displayed to your console. Can you edit your question and add a code snippet that shows the parsing of your input with the resulting error message(s)?

Comment: Not sure why but I am not able to edit my Own Question                                              I am following below steps.                                                                                        1. Written Grammar                                                                                                    2. "antlr4.bat" used to generate parser from grammar.                                                           3. "grun.bat" is used to generate token listed in question.                             I think I am missing to pass character encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. "grun.bat" is used to generate token

That just means your terminal cannot display the character properly. There is nothing wrong with the generated parser or lexer not being able to recognise `←`.

Just don't use the bat file, but rather test your lexer and parser by writing a small class yourself using your favourite IDE (which can display the characters properly).

Something like this:

```antlr
grammar T;

expression
 : ID ARROW NUMBER
 ;

ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
ARROW  : '←';
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

and a main class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("N ← 0"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    System.out.println(parser.expression().toStringTree(parser));
  }
}
```

which will display:

```
(expression N ← 0)
```

### EDIT

You could also try using the unicode escape for the arrow like this:

```antlr
grammar T;

expression
 : ID ARROW NUMBER
 ;

ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
ARROW  : '\u2190';
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

and the Java class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "N \u2190 0";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    System.out.println(source + ": " + parser.expression().toStringTree(parser));
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
N ← 0: (expression N ← 0)
```

Comment: I got following output line 1:1 token recognition error at: '←'
line 1:2 missing 'â†�' at '0'
(expression N <missing 'â†�'> 0)

Comment: Yes. Exactly same code. Just to confirm. I need to compile the grammar to generate the Parser ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart. After grammar edit and source edit it is giving me expected value.  I can update the grammar as per your suggestion but target source is not in my control.  Do you want me to replace ARROW from source code by Unicode character ?   Actually I have a long list of symbols.

Comment: That's entirely up to you :) Whatever works for you.

Comment: Now I am following your steps. I added duplicate question quite long back. Is there any place to find Unicode character mapping for symbols like you suggested '\u2190' for ARROW ?

Comment: No problem @SumitTyagi. Just out of curiosity, why are you writing a grammar/parser for APL? School/Uni project? It's a fun language!

Comment: @SumitTyagi which dialect are you using? It you're using Dyalog APL, there is `⎕UCS` which gives you Unicode-positions for any character argument you may provide. ie  `⎕ucs'←'` gives 8592.